# How to add radio buttons to rollover functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup for when the user hovers over `img1`, `img2` appears below `img1`. Also when hovering over `img3`, `img4` appears in the same place as `img2`.

What I would like to do is turn `img1` and `img3` into radio buttons so that not only do I have the above functionality but also when clicked `img3` remains visible until I decide to click on `img3` (which is another radio button).

```css
#img2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
#img1:hover + #img2,
#img2:hover {

display:block;
}


#img4 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

#img3:hover + #img4,
#img4:hover {

display:block;
}
```

```html
  <ul>

  <li>

     <img id="img1" src="imageone.png">

     <img id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">

     <img id="img3" src="imagethree.png">

     <img id="img4" src="imagefour.png">   

  </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: Basically, you need the same functionality, but with radio buttons?

Comment: Please clarify what your trying to do.

Comment: Yes I would like the same functionality except when you click on img1 I would like img2 to remain visible and when I click on img3 I would like img4 to remain visable and img2 to disappear.

Comment: I gave you an answer to just what you said now. and you down voted. maybe because your css doesnt apply them well and that you are using list of items(<li>). first you are using <ul><li></li></ul> which if any <li> is hidden, the next <li> takes it place, so you wont be able to say if its img2 or img4 that its been shown/hidden. so try using table that has cells, where img1 and img3 will be in the same row, while img2 and img4  on another row hidden for the hover action. the action you want is it click or hover

Comment: @Transformer I down voted because all you did was convert my CSS into Jquery. You did not answer the question in any way. I welcome your answers but please give example code because I still do not understand.

Comment: ok my offence was using jquery instead of css but the functionality you are talking of, is it with radio buttons

Comment: clarify me so i will know how to help guess i didnt understand ur question in the first place

Comment: I dont mind you using Jquery its just that I was hoping you could make sure that when img1 is clicked img2 stays visible until img3 is clicked. I would like the images to act as radio buttons yes. (In other words  the radio buttons should be hidden)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103442/discussion-between-transformer-and-billy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is exactly what you needed

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("img[id='img2']").css('display', 'none');
        $("img[id='img4']").css('display', 'none');
        
        $("img[id='img1']").click(function(){
            $("img[id='img2']").show();
            //this will do the radio button's job for clicked value i.e to keep track of when last img1 was clicked and remove from img3
            $("img[id='img1']").attr("click_checker", "yes");
            $("img[id='img3']").removeAttr("click_checker");
            $("img[id='img4']").hide();
        });
        $("img[id='img3']").click(function(){
            $("img[id='img4']").show();
            //this will do the radio button's job for clicked value i.e to keep track of when last img3 was clicked and remove from img1
            $("img[id='img3']").attr("click_checker", "yes");
            $("img[id='img1']").removeAttr("click_checker");
            $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        });
        
        $("img[id='img1']").mouseover(function(){
            $("img[id='img2']").show();
            $("img[id='img4']").hide();
        });
        $("img[id='img1']").mouseleave(function() {
            var img3_check = $("img[id='img3']").attr("click_checker");
            var img1_check = $("img[id='img1']").attr("click_checker");
            if (img3_check == 'yes') {
                //when mouse leaves we check if img3 has click_checker still on, then we show img4 if not both img2 and img4 will be hidden
                $("img[id='img2']").hide();
                $("img[id='img4']").show(); 
            } else if (img1_check == 'yes') {
                $("img[id='img2']").show();
            } else {
                 $("img[id='img2']").hide();
                 $("img[id='img4']").hide();
            }
         });

         $("img[id='img3']").mouseover(function(){
             $("img[id='img2']").hide();
             $("img[id='img4']").show();
         });
         $("img[id='img3']").mouseleave(function() {
             var img3_check = $("img[id='img3']").attr("click_checker");
             var img1_check = $("img[id='img1']").attr("click_checker");
             if (img1_check == 'yes') {
                   //when mouse leaves we check if img1 has click_checker still on, then we show img2 if not both img2 and img4 will be hidden
                 $("img[id='img2']").show();
                 $("img[id='img4']").hide(); 
             } else if (img3_check == 'yes') {
                $("img[id='img4']").show();
             } else {
                 $("img[id='img2']").hide();
                 $("img[id='img4']").hide();
             }
         });

    });
```

```css
#img2, #img4 {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
    <li>
       <img id="img1" src="http://www.julienlevesque.net/preview/google-smile-preview.jpg">
       <img id="img2" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/2.jpg">
       <img id="img3" src="http://www.julienlevesque.net/preview/google-smile-preview.jpg">
       <img id="img4" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/4.jpg">   
    </li>
    </ul>
```