# How to create mouseover and mouseleave effect within input and label elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here my aim is to replace the images wrapped up in labels with the list of images using the mouseover and mouseleave effect. I currently use the Jquery click functionality to show and hide the list of images.

**Example:**

If the mouse is over `img1` then `img2` appears and once the mouse leaves `img1` then `img2` disappears however once `img1` is clicked `img2` stays where it is. I would like the same functionality for the others so assuming we can now see `img2` I would like to see `img4` appear and `img2` dissappear if the mouse enters `img3` and then back `img2` if the mouse leaves.

Basically the same functionality as the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395745/how-to-add-radio-buttons-to-rollover-functionality)

HTML:

```
<div>

<input type="radio" value="1.0" id="b"/>
<label for="b"><img id="img1"  src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

<input type="radio" value="2.0" id="c">
<label for="c" ><img id="img3"  src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

<input type="radio" value="3.0" id="d"/>
<label for="d" ><img id="img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10"></label>

</div>

 <ul>
 <li>
       <img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
       <img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
       <img id="img6" src="http://lorempixel.com/10/10" style="position:absolute">
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}

#img1, #img3, #img5 {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
}

#img2{
bottom: 25px;
}
#img4 {
bottom: 50px;
}
#img6 {
bottom: 75px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
   $("img[id='img2']").css({"display": "none"});
   $("img[id='img4']").css({"display": "none"});
   $("img[id='img6']").css({"display": "none"});

    $("#img1").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img2']").show();
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();
        $("img[id='img6']").hide();
    });

    $("img[id='img3']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img4']").show();
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img6']").hide();
    });

     $("img[id='img5']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img6']").show();
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqb0oyy4/)

Comment: Well you do nothing onmouseleave portion of hover

Comment: You're right I've edited the question to make it more suitable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either use classes to keep track of the states. Or you can make objects of each of the images and add properties that keep track of the states. I made an example for you
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/e393b2hm/2/)

```
img1 = {
  node: $('#img1'),
  target: $('img[id=img2]'),
  clicked: false
};

img3 = {
    node: $('#img3'),
  target: $('img[id=img4]'),
  clicked: false
};

img5 = {
    node: $('#img5'),
  target: $('img[id=img6]'),
  clicked: false
};
```